Animating a position change in a ScrollView

I'm sorry for the pseudo-code, but I'm not allowed to share my code.

I have a ScrollView that contains pinned items in the top and unpinned items in the bottom.
 ______________
|    Item 1    |
|    Item 2    |
|    Item 3    |
|--------------|
|    Item 4    |
|    Item 5    |
|    Item 6    |
|    Item 7    |
|    Item 8    |
|______________|

The Scroll view is populated by two collections (pinnedItems and unpinnedItems) using two ForEach-clauses in the ScrollView.
var pinnedItems = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
var unpinnedItems = ["Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6", "Item 7", "Item 8"]

ScrollView {
    ForEach(pinnedTasks) { task in
        NavigationLink(value: NavigationPath.task(task)) {
            TaskCardView(task: task, onPinning: {
                withAnimation {
                    togglePinnedTask(task: task)
                }
            })
            .padding(.bottom)
        }.buttonStyle(.plain)
    }


    Divider()
        .frame(minHeight: 3)
        .background(.gray)
        .padding(.bottom)


    ForEach(unPinnedTasks) { task in
        NavigationLink(value: NavigationPath.task(task)) {
            TaskCardView(task: task, onPinning: {
                withAnimation {
                    togglePinnedTask(task: task)
                }
            })
            .padding(.bottom)
        }.buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
}
                

The togglePinnedTask() function removes the task from one collection and inserts it into the other.
The automatic animation just fades the task cards. I would like to make them "fly" to their new position. What it the approach to do this?

You can use matchedGeometryEffect. Here is a simple example:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var pinnedItems = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
    @State private var unpinnedItems = ["Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6", "Item 7", "Item 8"]
    @Namespace var ns
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(pinnedItems, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text(item)
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: item, in: ns)
                    }
                    ForEach(unpinnedItems, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text(item)
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: item, in: ns)
                    }
                }
            }

            // as an example to trigger the animation
            Button("Change Pins") {
                withAnimation {
                    pinnedItems.append(unpinnedItems.removeLast())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Note that in both matchedGeometryEffects and the ForEaches, I have used the item itself as the id. In your real code, your items probably conform to Identifiable and you should use their id property instead.

Thanks, this works really well. I'd wish I could show you the result. :-)
Can you explain the concept @Namespace and what it does? I'm new to that term.

@esbenr It's just for namespacing the ids (like providing a "scope" for them, in a sense), so that SwiftUI doesn't confuse them with ids in other namespaces. For example, you could have other matchedGeometryEffects in other views, and with the same ids as these items. If they are in different namespaces, then all is good. :)

Thank you, that makes sense. Learned something new today.
